# Simplemodal : Destroy data after closing

Tags: simplemodal

I'm a bit stuck with Simplemodal.

I want to destroy the data which has the class $('p.confirm') after closing the modal window.

Here's what i have so far and it doesn't work :

```
if (document.getElementsByClassName('confirm').length > 0){

    $('p.confirm').modal({
        overlayClose:true,
        onClose:function(dialog){
            dialog.data.find('.confirm').remove();

            $.modal.close(); // must call this!
        },
        persist:true

    });

    }
```

Can anybody help me ? Thanks

Comment: Do you want to remove `p.confirm` after close?

Comment: Yes, i want to remove it

Comment: Let me know if its what you search for http://jsfiddle.net/3RV8C/5/

Comment: Thank you Chris, that'ss exactly what i want to achieve. I didn't know that $.modal.close() had to be called at first in my function

Answer (score 0):

```
<p class="confirm">asdf</p>

if (document.getElementsByClassName('confirm').length > 0){

    $('p.confirm').modal({
        overlayClose: true,
        onClose: function(dialog){

            $.modal.close(); // must call this!
            dialog.data[0].remove();


        },
        persist:true

    });
}
```